PowerApp: dropdown choices generated by formula
I need your helpdesk please as I have no idea to solve my issue.
In my canvas app I have a dropdown which can have the folliwing values:

Bull/Bear
Heaven/Earth
Young/Old
Etc....

In a second dropdown I would like to have the following choises if have choosen Bull/Bear in the first dropdown:

Bull
Bear

If the first dropdown will be changed to e.g. Young/Old, the second dropdown should change to the choices 1. Young 2. Old
I was able to show only one of both in the second dropdown but not both.
Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.
I thought i can use the same formula which is working for one choice by putting it in the dropdown Logik [formula1,formula2]
...but did not work

Dropdown2 Items property should be:
Split(Dropdown1.Selected.Value,"/")
